# bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm beginner with C and I am learning on my own.
I am trying to convert an int to binary for bitwise operations, and I am not really sure how to do it? I have tried to use mod and other mathematics to do it, but I have been unsuccessful. I have searched around and have not found a clear way of this. Please assist.

Comment: If you are curious about bitwise operators/operations, see this brief [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to do any conversion of an `int` to use bitwise operators on it. They automatically work on the *bits* that compose the `int`.

If you want to view the binary representation of a number, you can use (assuming the 8 least significant bits)...

```
int num = 4;

int i;

for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", (num >> i) & 1);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/n4AUWiyL).

This uses bitwise operators `>>` (right shift) and `&` (and).

Answer (score 4):

It's already represented in the computer as binary! (Unless you have one of those ternary computers.) So go ahead and use bitwise operators on your `int`s. (Works even if you *do* have one of those ternary computers.)

[See? It works!](http://codepad.org/7s1MYMwG)